# I want a more personalized BalloonHint (Background color/Rounded Corner/transparency)

Tags: delphi, hint, balloon

When using `TballoonHint`, I need it more personalized in colors, shape, transparency and animated appearance, how can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create your own descendant of `TBalloonHint` or `THintWindow`. Override the `NCPaint` method to draw the outer edges (non-client area) and `CalcHintRect` (if needed), and provide your own `Paint` method to draw the interior as you'd like it to appear.

Then assign it to `Application.HintWindowClass` in your .dpr file just before the call to `Application.Run`.

Here's a (very minimal) example that does nothing but paint the standard hint window with a green background.

Save this as **MyHintWindow.pas**:

```
unit MyHintWindow;

interface

uses
  Windows, Controls;

type
  TMyHintWindow=class(THintWindow)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure NCPaint(DC: HDC); override;
  public
    function CalcHintRect(MaxWidth: Integer; const AHint: string; AData: Pointer): TRect;
      override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Graphics;

{ TMyHintWindow }

function TMyHintWindow.CalcHintRect(MaxWidth: Integer; 
  const AHint: string; AData: Pointer): TRect;
begin
  // Does nothing but demonstrate overriding.
  Result := inherited CalcHintRect(MaxWidth, AHint, AData);
  // Change window size if needed, using Windows.InflateRect with Result here
end;

procedure TMyHintWindow.NCPaint(DC: HDC);
begin
  // Does nothing but demonstrate overriding. Changes nothing.
  // Replace drawing of non-client (edges, caption bar, etc.) with your own code
  // here instead of calling inherited. This is where you would change shape 
  // of hint window
  inherited NCPaint(DC);
end;

procedure TMyHintWindow.Paint;
begin
  // Draw the interior of the window. This is where you would change inside color,
  // draw icons or images or display animations. This code just changes the
  // window background (which it probably shouldn't do here, but is for demo 
  // purposes only.
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

A sample project to use it:

- Create a new VCL forms application.
- Set the `Form1.ShowHint` property to `True` in the Object Inspector.
- Drop any control (a `TEdit`, for instance) on the form, and put some text in it's `Hint` property.
- Use the **Project->View Source** menu to display the project source.

Add the indicated lines to the project source:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  MyHintWindow,                // Add this line
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  HintWindowClass := TMyHintWindow;      // Add this line
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Sample output (ugly, but it works):

[image: Image of memo control with ugly green hint popup]

Comment: Thank you but could you give me the code , I am not an expert in Delphi.

Comment: Thank you  Ken White, it is very helpful .

Comment: You do the same thing, except you descend from the balloon hint window instead. I'm not going to spoon-feed you the code;  I've shown you what you need to do. You need to figure out how to make it work for your needs now. :-)

Comment: type
  TMyHintWindow=class(TBalloonHint)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure NCPaint(DC: HDC); override;

Comment: <code>type
  TMyHintWindow=class(TBalloonHint)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
    procedure NCPaint(DC: HDC); override;
</code>