# Change font for Tballoonhint (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

When I use the TBalloonhint (delphi) component I can not find how to change the default font. Is there any way?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20750099/62576), which shows you how to descend from TBalloonHint to change it's appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Simple but not recommended: you may adjust the font by using Screen.HintFont property. I would not recommend this method as you need to disable Theme support in your application (Project Options\Application\Runtime Themes = None)
2. You may implement your own TBalloonHint component. I assume it should be very easy. As you could find in Delphi sources TBalloonHint has two methods only (`PaintHint` and `SetHintSize`). You may take VCL implementation and remove theme support from it (assume IsThemed = false).

Comment: Max, Thanks for your help. I will explode implement my own component.